# segmentation of the source image in opencv based on canny edge outline attained from processing the said source image

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-segmentation, canny-operator

I have a source image. I need a particular portion to be segmented from it and save it as another image. I have the canny outline of the portion I need to be segmented out,but how do I use it to cut the portion from the source image? I have attached both the source image and the canny edge outline. Please help me and suggest me a solution.

[image: Source Image]

[image: Canny edge]

EDIT-1: Alexander Kondratskiy,Is this what you meant by filling the boundary?[image]

EDIT-2 : according to Kannat, I have done this
[image: source Image with contour]

Now how do I separate the regions that are outside and inside of the contour into two separate images?

Edit 3- I thought of 'And-ing'the mask and the contour lined source image.Since I am using C, I am having a little difficulty.
this is the code I use to and:-

```
            hsv_gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(seg->width, seg->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );                       
                    cvCvtColor( seg, hsv_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );                       
                    hsv_mask=cvCloneImage(hsv_gray);
            IplImage* contourImg =cvCreateImage( cvSize(hsv_mask->width, hsv_mask->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );                      
            IplImage* newImg=cvCreateImage( cvSize(hsv_mask->width, hsv_mask->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
            cvAnd(contourImg, hsv_mask,newImg,NULL);
```

I always get an error of mismatch size or Type. I adjusted the size but I can't seem to adjust the type,since one(hsv_mask) is 1 channel and the others are 3 channels.

@kanat- I also tried your boundingrect but could not seem to get in right in C format.

Comment: Use copyTo with the mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cv::findContours` on your second image to find the contour of the segment. Then use `cv::boundingRect` to find bounding box for this segment. After that you can create matrix and save in it cropped bounding box from your second image (as I see it is a binary image). To crop needed region use this:

`cv::getRectSubPix(your_image, BB_size, cv::Point(BB.x + BB.width/2, 
BB.y + BB.height/2), new_image)`.
Then you can save `new_image` using `cv::imwrite`. That's it.

EDIT:

If you found only one contour then use this (else you will iterate through elements of found contours). The following code shows the steps but sorry I can't test it now:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
// cv::findContours(..., contours, ...);
cv::Rect BB = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours[0]));
cv::Mat new_image;
cv::getRectSubPix(your_image, BB.size(), cv::Point(BB.x + BB.width/2, 
BB.y + BB.height/2), new_image);
cv::imwrite("new_image_name.jpg", new_image);
```

Comment: kanat, I have done the contour part,but I am having trouble coding the boundingRect part,...

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai, Sorry for late reply, I edited the answer.

Comment: @kanat- what If I "and" it with the filled mask?

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai, It seems like I misunderstood the question then. Yeap, using "and" works fine.

Comment: @kanat- not sound needy,,but can help me with this ... I need the code in c,not C++. I have tried but keeping getting errors.

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai, in your edited code numbers of channels are 3 and 1 in two images you used in cvAnd. This gives an error. Forget about boundingRect, it was inappropriate solution. You can use cvAnd(original_image, filled_image, new_image). If filled image has different image type from original, use cvCvtColor to convert to the same type. Then it is gonna be cvAnd(original_image, converted_image, new_image).

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the boundary created by the canny-edge detector, and use that as an alpha mask on the original image.